# Print elements of list horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list: lista=[[2], [1, 2], [2], [3], [3]]  and I need it to print it like this:

```
      1
  2   2   2   3   3
```

How can I do it?
**I've tried:**

```
for x in a:
    for e in x:
        print(str(e) + '  ', end='')
```

**This is what I obtained:**

```
2   1   2   2   3   3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.  You should show what you've tried, as folks here tend to frown on requests to write code

Comment: ok thank you for the tip, I willl have it in consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a silly one-liner version:

```
def print_table(seq, width=3):
    print('\n'.join([''.join(
        [(str(u[-i]) if len(u) >= i else '').rjust(width) for u in seq])
            for i in range(max(len(u) for u in seq), 0, -1)]))
```

And here's the same algorithm in a somewhat more readable form:

```
def get_cell(u, i):
    return str(u[-i]) if len(u) >= i else ''

def print_table(seq, width=3):
    maxlen = max(len(u) for u in seq)
    for i in range(maxlen, 0, -1):
        row = [get_cell(u, i).rjust(width) for u in seq]
        print(''.join(row))

#Test
lista=[[2], [1, 2], [2], [3], [3]]
listb=[[4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 6], [7], [8]]

print(lista)
print_table(lista)
print('-' * 20)

print(listb)
print_table(listb)
```

**output**

```
[[2], [1, 2], [2], [3], [3]]
     1         
  2  2  2  3  3
--------------------
[[4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 6], [7], [8]]
        1      
     2  3      
  4  5  6  7  8
```

I won't explain exactly how this code works, since I suspect that this is a homework question.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I really appreciate it!